# Caching of JS and CSS files – Apache mod_headers doesn’t take effect

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, apache2, http-headers, cache-control

As suggested by [an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118886/2407870), I'm trying using a version number on my JS and CSS files so that the browser will only make a request when the JS or CSS version number is changed in my PHP file. To facilitate this, I have a rewrite in my `httpd.conf` which transforms a requested file like `myscript--20140904.js` to `myscript.js`. Since I'm doing things this way, I want the browser to cache the file for a long time, since it will see a request for a "different" file when that version number is updated.

According to [an answer on Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/5282), I can use `FilesMatch` along with `Header set Cache-Control` to only cache the CSS/JS files with the version number on them.

And according to [an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5823521/2407870), only `Cache-Control` is necessary, since it takes precedence over `Expires` anyway.

But this is not working. The `Cache-Control` header field is missing from the response.

Here's my Apache configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\-\-.+\.(css|js)$ $1.$2

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "^(.*)\-\-.+\.(js|css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15552000"
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# <IfModule mod_expires.c>
#     <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
#         ExpiresActive On
#         ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 months"
#         ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 months"
#     </FilesMatch>
# </IfModule>
```

Here's a request for one of the JS files:

```
http://localhost/[url]/common.js

GET [url]/common.js HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost/[refererUrl]
Cookie: PHPSESSID=[cookie]
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 04 Sep 2014 19:45:32 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 03 Sep 2014 22:55:57 GMT
Etag: [etag]
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5167
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Comment: Have you tried it without using `<IfModule mod_headers.c>`, FilesMatch should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FilesMatch "^(.*)\-\-.+\.(js|css)$">
```

`FilesMatch` takes a *filename* and matches against the file system, not the URL. The underlying file is still called "myscript.js", so this pattern should be something like: `\.(js|css)$`

(Aside... your example request appears to be for `common.js` - which wouldn't have matched your pattern anyway - shouldn't this be for `common--20140904.js`?)

Comment: Whoops, using common.js was a typo. I was picking them from a list of headers. The info otherwise was the same though.

Comment: Are you saying I should be using something other than FilesMatch? I was matching the filename, not the url.

Comment: No, I think `FilesMatch` should be OK. However, you weren't matching the filename, you were trying to match the URL. The regex `^(.*)\-\-.+\.(js|css)$` would only match a filename of the form `common--20140904.js`, but that is the URL. The filename is simply `common.js`, which the regex would _not_ match.

Comment: Oh, I see now... Yes, you're totally right. Thanks!